# Getting Rocketchat History in React

Tags: reactjs, rest, fetch-api, rocket.chat

im writing a simple chat client for Rocket.Chat in React.
At the moment its possible to send messages to the server and show the sent message in the message list.
Now I want the Client to get the last messages from the server and show it in my message list.
There is an API Endpoint for this: https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/channels/history .

I want to know how to implement it in my MessageList.js Component so that it will be shown correctly in the chat history.

Thats my code of the component at the moment:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import Message from '../Message/Message'
import './MessageList.css'

class MessageList extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        messages: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        messages: [],
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {

        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/channels.history?roomId=drtWNMjAmKM86hnxp', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'X-Auth-Token': '0qZt4LEd2pWHdCcjxFA-yn9RdOMdKpLMJPC-ejFDUCj',
                'X-User-Id': 'JTFuq3JpgchDJT3Wb',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        })


        console.log("Component did mount")

    }

    componentDidUpdate = () => {
        this.node.scrollTop = this.node.scrollHeight

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="MessageList" ref={(node) => (this.node = node)}>
                {this.props.messages.map((message, i) => (
                    <Message key={i} {...message} />
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default MessageList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easier to fetch the Data in the App component, give it into the state and push it down to the message list.

```
// getting the Message History and set it to the State
    axios.get(
        window.url+'channels.historyroomId='+window.roomId,
        {headers: {
            'X-Auth-Token' : window.authToken,
            'X-User-Id' : window.userId,
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
        }
    )

        .then(res => {
            const messages = res.data.messages;
            messages.reverse();
            this.setState({ messages });
        });
```

and then:

```
<MessageList messages={this.state.messages} />
```